# Sending PUT request to WebAPI getting error that requested resource does not support GET

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-6

Currently, when sending a PUT request to our production server, we are recieving the following error: `{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."}`

I get this error both when I use an ajax method against that put URL and when I use Fiddler2 and force it to be a PUT request.

The kicker is that this works just fine on our staging server. I'm sure its some form of IIS configuration issue, however I don't see anything different and I'm at a loss of things to try.

**Server Environment:** 2003 Server IIS 6, using .net 4 MVC WebAPI

Attempted Fixes:

- Enabling All Verbs for .axd
- WildCard Mapping

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Is your staging server environment identical to your production server environment?

Comment: Both are 2003 environments running IIS6. Unfortunately beyond that I can't verify that they are the same. I fear that issue is because of this.